# ERROR: Failed building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport when deploying app in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

This is my first attempt at learning Git and using Heroku and I am hitting a hurdle on the deployment.

The project is https://github.com/geordiefrost/boxscores but when I deploy in Heroku I get the following error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: Protego, PyDispatcher, twisted-iocpsupport
         Building wheel for Protego (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for Protego (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for Protego: filename=Protego-0.1.16-py3-none-any.whl size=7782 sha256=7a984b098145551731c79e0e49950e7cd3ffae119aba714ef086db51d360e042
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-ld7bhu_v/wheels/9b/e7/dd/5c83b657359b8cc1e116bfab153f22ee891862f6d78d1ddb82
         Building wheel for PyDispatcher (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for PyDispatcher (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for PyDispatcher: filename=PyDispatcher-2.0.5-py3-none-any.whl size=11515 sha256=25a2e20afabd2bf4b4bb584b22fab02f9f200e017a80a94c79f6a2d9e40e501c
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-ld7bhu_v/wheels/a5/de/8a/4b52190a95d99c042ec6bd5ad2de3a3c1b5ce71d69f0bbd036
         Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml): started
         Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
         ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
          command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpgz9ows_m
              cwd: /tmp/pip-install-xuedwuh8/twisted-iocpsupport_3351c38841ae47838e63af93b9daf44b
         Complete output (13 lines):
         running bdist_wheel
         running build
         running build_ext
         building 'twisted_iocpsupport.iocpsupport' extension
         creating build
         creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
         creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/twisted_iocpsupport
         gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Itwisted_iocpsupport -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9 -c twisted_iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/twisted_iocpsupport/iocpsupport.o
         twisted_iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c:641:10: fatal error: io.h: No such file or directory
           641 | #include "io.h"
               |          ^~~~~~
         compilation terminated.
         error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
         ----------------------------------------
         ERROR: Failed building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport
       Successfully built Protego PyDispatcher
       Failed to build twisted-iocpsupport
       ERROR: Could not build wheels for twisted-iocpsupport, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=twisted_iocpsupport%2Fiocpsupport.c+fatal+error%3A+io.h%3A+No+such+file+or+directory